# C.P (unknown abbreviation, control cabinet drawing)

Tags: components, control, panel

I don't know what "C.P" might stand for in a HVAC control cabinet drawing. Could anyone have a quick look? I'm not an electrical engineer, but a translator. Not sure what electrical component is designated this way. All I know is that the system is manufactured by a Korean company named Kiturami Bumyang Air Conditioning Co., Ltd. Please, see the picture attached, item No.2. 
Sorry for poor quality, that's how it is in the manual.

[image: HVAC system control cabinet]

[image: Cabinet outside view]

Comment: I don't think it is Control Panel. The entire cabinet is referred to as Control Panel (added a new drawing), with a touch screen HMI and stuff on the front door. Just attached an outside view pic above.

Comment: My first thought was control processor, but that's #7. It seems to refer to the block directly above it, are they connection points? What do you think NFB means?

Comment: They might be connection points, thanks for the idea... I guess NFB is a no-fuse breaker

Comment: Connection Points sounds reasonable, they look like DIN rail terminals. NFB is possibly a breaker of some sort.

Comment: Control Power.  Try that.

Answer (score 1):

It's not uncommon for the inlet breaker to be followed by breakers for each circuit, and the modules in the picture looks about the right size, so CP could be 'circuit protection'.

Answer (score 0):

It could be either "Control Panel" or "Control Point". 
It looks like a screw terminal which could be used to connect a front control panel. 
It could also simply be control test points.